# Position absolute not working properly in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-position

I am coding a basic template, but i am facing a problem with Internet Explorer 8. I have created a Slider Carousel and i have put it in a position absolute in order to display it little bit more on the top. In firefox, chroome and Safari there is any problem but in Internet Explorer 8 it's happening that the content after the carousel is not displayed correctly

Why this is happening? how can i fix this problem in IE?

[Here](http://experiments.hostzi.com/landing/) you can see the template:

A print screen also of what is happening in IE[image]

This is my html:

```
    <div class="container-carousel container ">
        <article id="carousel">
            <div class="row">
                <div id="lista1" class="als-container">
                <span class="als-prev"><img src="images/left_arrow.png" alt="prev" title="precedente" /></span>
                    <div class="als-viewport">
                        <ul class="als-wrapper">
                            <li class="als-item"><img src="images/als-images/social.png" alt="social" title="social" /><h3>Appz Theme</h3><hr><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,<br>omnis euismod indoctum mel.</p></li>
                            <li class="als-item"><img src="images/als-images/android.png" alt="android" title="android" /><h3>Easy to use</h3><hr><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,<br>omnis euismod indoctum mel.</p></li>
                            <li class="als-item"><img src="images/als-images/apple.png" alt="apple" title="apple" /><h3>Amazing design</h3><hr><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,<br>omnis euismod indoctum mel.</p></li>
                            <li class="als-item"><img src="images/als-images/google.jpg" alt="google" title="google" /><h3>Dashboard view</h3><hr><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,<br>omnis euismod indoctum mel.</p></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                <span class="als-next"><img src="images/right_arrow.png" alt="next" title="successivo" /></span>
            </div>      
       </article>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
            <div class="application">
                <p>Get your <span class="bold">free</span> <a class="mainbutton" href="">Download</a> of <span class="app">App</span> today!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Your code is so bad, my Safari is choking out on it.  Try fixing your very serious HTML errors first.  See: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fexperiments.hostzi.com%2Flanding%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: Thanks Sparky! there was an unclosed element, that was the problem, so appreciate..now how can you look in safari?

Comment: I turned my comment into an answer.  But I cannot open your site at all.  Keeps giving me a _"the server where this page is located isn't responding"_ error.

Comment: Ok, it's free hosting... could be lots of issues with that.  http://www.000webhost.com/faq.php?ID=62

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have invalid HTML as per the W3C online validator.

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fexperiments.hostzi.com%2Flanding%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Answer (score 1):

Some times ie cant support article, change to div.